# listview itemtapped is not working on the ios using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am using xamarin forms. I am using listview. When I clicked on the item of listview, for android, it will go to the corresponding page. But on iOS, itemtapped event throws exception error. I give the code and exception below:

In xaml file:

```
<ListView ItemTapped="FirmFirstLst_ItemTapped" x:Name="FirmFirstLst_ItemTapped" IsGroupingEnabled = "true"  SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Frame Padding="0"  CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding framebackcolor, Converter={StaticResource BacgroundColorConverter}}" OutlineColor="{Binding outlinecolor, Converter={StaticResource BacgroundColorConverter}}" Margin="10, 3, 10, 3" VerticalOptions="Center" HasShadow="False">
                                            <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,5,5,5" Padding="0" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="{Binding backgroundColor, Converter={StaticResource BacgroundColorConverter}}">
                                                <Grid Margin="10,5,10,5" RowSpacing="5" >
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition>
                                                            <RowDefinition.Height>
                                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Android="38" iOS="25"/>
                                                            </RowDefinition.Height>
                                                        </RowDefinition>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{OnIdiom Phone= {OnPlatform iOS=73, Android=85}, Tablet= {OnPlatform iOS=*, Android=*}}">
                                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding NewTime}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" FontFamily="lato" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Small" ></Label>
                                                        <Label x:Name="Reqalue" Text="{Binding NewValue}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" FontFamily="lato" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Micro" ></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding NewDpTime}"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" FontFamily="lato" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Micro" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"></Label>
                                                        <Label x:Name="ETAvalue" Text="{Binding Etue}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" FontFamily="lato" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Micro" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Site}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontFamily="lato" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="NoWrap">
                                                        <Label.TranslationX>
                                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                                <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="-18" Android="-15" />
                                                                </OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="0" Android="0" />
                                                                </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                            </OnIdiom>
                                                        </Label.TranslationX>
                                                    </Label>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Rate}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontFamily="lato" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Small" >
                                                        <Label.TranslationX>
                                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                                <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="-18" Android="-15" />
                                                                </OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="0" Android="0" />
                                                                </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                            </OnIdiom>
                                                        </Label.TranslationX>
                                                    </Label>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="White" FontFamily="lato"  FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"></Label>
                                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="25"  HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TranslationX="4" TranslationY="3"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell Height="25">
                                        <ViewCell.View>
                                            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Key}" TextColor="Blue" FontFamily="Roboto" FontAttributes="None"  FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ViewCell.View>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In xaml.cs file:

```
public async void FirmFirstLst_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                    var farmselecteddata = e.Item as ListDetails;
                    FirmDetails page = new FirmDetails();
                    await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logs.LogCreate("FirmFirstLst_ItemTapped Ex : " + ex + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Exception on Catch statement:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.CalculateAutoCells (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x101241e30 + 0x00494> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.MeasureGrid (System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Boolean requestSize) <0x101244940 + 0x0004b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012414e0 + 0x0005f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedView.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012c2d70 + 0x000f3> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedView.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012c2d70 + 0x000f3> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1011e3530 + 0x00167> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.View child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region, Xamarin.Forms.SizeRequest childSizeRequest) <0x10125ca80 + 0x00693> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012b3c50 + 0x0020b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012414e0 + 0x0035f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.View child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region, Xamarin.Forms.SizeRequest childSizeRequest) <0x10125ca80 + 0x00693> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012b3c50 + 0x0020b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012414e0 + 0x0035f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x101291500 + 0x003ff> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012414e0 + 0x0035f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10125c380 + 0x0052f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10125c310 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x005b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10127b780 + 0x003f7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10127c280 + 0x00473> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10127c250 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d7b40 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) <0x1012d2930 + 0x000d7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) <0x1012d54c0 + 0x00033> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) <0x10125ba80 + 0x00237> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10127b780 + 0x003f7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.UpdateChildrenLayout () <0x10127c280 + 0x00473> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x10127c250 + 0x00023> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) <0x1012d6290 + 0x0002f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnChildMeasureInvalidated (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.InvalidationTrigger trigger) <0x10127c860 + 0x001db> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnChildMeasureInvalidated (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) <0x10127c020 + 0x000b7> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InvalidateMeasureInternal (Xamarin.Forms.Internals.InvalidationTrigger trigger) <0x1012d6820 + 0x0006b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_IsPlatformEnabled (System.Boolean value) <0x1012d4510 + 0x0004f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform+<>c.<.cctor>b__51_0 (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldvalue, System.Object newvalue) <0x101148ff0 + 0x0006f> in <7402bf39df944a9ebf61606e5f9c45a4#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) <0x1011f4e00 + 0x002cf> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) <0x1011f3e90 + 0x0054b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) <0x1011f4ce0 + 0x0009f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) <0x1011f24c0 + 0x0002b> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.SetRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement bindable, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer value) <0x1010d3be0 + 0x00033> in <7402bf39df944a9ebf61606e5f9c45a4#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.CreateViewControllerForPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) <0x1010fdb30 + 0x00033> in <7402bf39df944a9ebf61606e5f9c45a4#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) <0x101157a10 + 0x0008b> in <7402bf39df944a9ebf61606e5f9c45a4#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.PushAsyncInner (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) <0x101275970 + 0x00247> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) <0x101274880 + 0x0054f> in <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 
  at MyPrj.Form.FarmLoad.FirmFirstLst_ItemTapped (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e) <0x100ab0be0 + 0x00897> in <c4f4691ea25041bcbf76ea1127002f81#034e084c54ab7bbcccd562025a82b9f8>:0 13-02-2020 15:26:06
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: this appears to be a problem in FirmDetails, not the ListView

Comment: You have something wrong in the FirmDetails, maybe something in the CodeBehind or some {OnPlatform } set in your xaml, are you doing something in your codebehind?

Comment: ```new FirmDetails(farmselecteddata); ```?

Comment: Hi , you need to check which line code occurs error in `FirmFirstLst_ItemTapped` method first .